# Handlebars not populating template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template and I'm trying to use it, but when I do, I get all the tags but with no text. Here's my HTML:

```
<script src="../static/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <li class="message">
            <h6>{{username}}</h6>
            <p>{{message}}</p>
            <p>{{date}}</p>
        </li>
    </script>
```

And in main.js:

```
socket.on('message', data => {
        console.log('message recieved')
        console.log(data.channel)
        console.log(document.querySelector("#active").innerHTML)
        if (data.channel === document.querySelector("#active").innerHTML) {
            console.log(data.sent_by)
            console.log(data.message)
            console.log(data.time)
            var template = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML);
            console.log(document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML)
            const context = {'username' : data.sent_by,
                            'message' : data.message,
                            'date' : data.time,};
            var html = template(context);
            console.log(context)
            console.log(html)
            document.querySelector('#view-message').innerHTML += html
        } 
    })
```

All log messages are being run so the socket is receiving data and the if condition is being triggered. I've used handlebars in a previous section of the same project and it worked fine there so I'm not sure why it's not working here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

move your script `<script src="../static/js/main.js"></script>` all the way to the bottom

Comment: I moved it behind all the other scripts but before the body tag, still no change

Comment: your body tag should be on top then the jquery script , handlebars script,socketio,the template and then main.js

Comment: Currently, it's ```    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <li class="message">
            <h6>{{username}}</h6>
            <p>{{message}}</p>
            <p>{{date}}</p>
        </li>
    </script>
    <script src="../static/js/main.js"></script>
</html>``` Still no use. I think it might be in the code now.

Comment: check the browser console and tell me what do you see ?? also to eliminate any errors in terms of script path, make a script tag and past your main.js code in it and put it at the bottom and remove ./static/js... for now

Comment: Console is clean, no errors. I've tried directly pasting it, still no success. Javascript code: https://gist.github.com/hlee131/b87e03f2a4abbe677ead4300ee346a14.

Comment: are you sure you receive the data inside the if statement ? can you console.log that?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but since by html isn't too complicated, I'm just going to revert to Javascript template literals.